# Direct links to Twilio Console resources within sub-accounts

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to create URLs that point to the Twilio Console page for a specific resource (e.g. a **Call** or a **Conversation**), even if that resource exists in a sub-account?

My use case is a back-office web app where I would like to give users the option to easily open up the Twilio resources corresponding to our entities&processes. I'm currently trying it with URLs like these:

```
https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/logs/CA…
https://www.twilio.com/console/chat/services/IS…/channels/CH…
```

This works for resources in one sub-account, but not others (confusingly regardless of which sub-account was "active" in the Console before opening the link). For channels/conversations, I'm getting a Console page with error messages; for calls it's a 502/Bad Gateway error

Is there any way to supply the sub-account ID as a parameter to URLs like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, as of now, not possible.

PS: Maybe the [Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-call-logs) can help you to retrieve and display the required information in your web app.

Comment: Thank you! That's a pity… feel free to pass it on as a feature request :)